# Presenting view from app delegate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am working on a project in which I need to present login page each time the app enters fore ground from back ground. I wanted to present a model viewcontroller but Model view is not supported.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: First you need to work on your accept-rate by accepting answers to your old questions. Then tell us a little bit more about your app hierarchy and what you have tried so far.

Comment: by "model" do you mean "modal"? if so, in what sense is it not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. Once you get the notification, show your login view controller using [self presentmodelviewcontroller:view animated:YES];